# bootstrap scrollspy offset Height not working in firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I use this script for scrollspy offset height in my bootstrap theme. This code doesnt work properly in firefox and the heght offset aint operate, this works on chrome.

```
var offsetHeight = 120;
    $("#p-menu a[href^='#']").on('click', function(e) {

   // prevent default anchor click behavior
   e.preventDefault();

   // store hash
   var hash = this.hash;

   // animate
   $('html, body').animate({
       scrollTop: $(this.hash).offset().top-offsetHeight}, 300, function(){

       // when done, add hash to url
       // (default click behaviour)
       window.location.hash = hash;
     });

    });
```

HTML:

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs bg" role="tablist" id="p-menu">
      <div class="container">
        <a href="#info" data-scroll="#info" class="product-scrollspy active"><i id="info-icon"></i><span>Informations</span></a>
        <a href="#details" data-scroll="#details" class="product-scrollspy "><i id="details-icon"></i><span>Specifications</span></a>
        <a href="#comments" data-scroll="#comments" class="product-scrollspy "><i id="comments-icon"></i><span>Comments</span></a>
        <a href="#diagram" data-scroll="#diagram" class="product-scrollspy "><i id="diagram-icon"></i><span>Diagram</span></a>
      </div>
    </ul>

    <div class="row bg" id="info" data-spy="scroll" data-target=".navbar-example">
        <div class="p_info" id="details">
          ...
        </div>

        <div class="p_info" id="comments">
          ...
        </div>
        <div class="p_info" id="diagram">
          ...
        </div>       
    </div>
```

Comment: please provide the html as well

Comment: @OnlyMAJ I added the HTML code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same Problem and solved it with this

```
history.pushState(null, null, myHash);
```

instead of

```
window.location.hash = myHash;
```